# Change only certain arguments in a class/method, hold others constant

Tags: python, arguments, wrapper

I have a class & method, each with several arguments: `my_class(a,b,c).my_method(d,e,f)` and I'd like to be able to only change a single argument, while holding the others constant.

Constantly copy-pasting the other constant arguments seems bad, so I'd like to create a new object `wrapper_fct` where I reference `my_class` but only provide the one argument I want to change, `b`, without always having to specify the remaining arguments. How would `wrapper_fct()` look like?

For example, `wrapper_fct(my_class, b1)` would return `my_class(a,b1,c).my_method(d,e,f)`, `wrapper_fct(my_class, b2)` would return `my_class(a,b2,c).my_method(d,e,f)`.

Here's an example in practice:

Loop through just the variable `b` and evaluate several classes/methods for each new instance of `b`, and append the results in a list.
I can currently do this in a `for` loop:

```
mylist1 = [] # init lists (append results here)
mylist2 = []
mylist2 = []

for b in  [1,2,3,4,5]:
   mylist1.append( my_class1(a,b,c).my_method(d,e,f) )
   mylist2.append( my_class2(a,b,c).my_method(d,e,f) )
   mylist3.append( my_class3(a,b,c).my_method(d,e,f) )
   ...
```

But it seems better to create a function `loop_through_B()` and use the `wrapper_fct(my_class,b)` as specified above. Not sure if it's the ideal solution, but maybe something like:

```
def loop_through_B(input_class, b_values = [1,2,3,4,5])
    mylist = []
    for b in b_values:
        mylist.append( wrapper_fct(input_class,b) )
    return mylist        

loop_through_B(my_class1) # would I also have to specify the method here as well?
loop_through_B(my_class2)
loop_through_B(my_class3)
```

Extra Question: how would I add the ability to vary method arguments, or even multiple class & method arguments?

Comment: @martineau Yeah, for brevity I omitted the part where I use the output of the property. In my case, I actually append the results from each class in a list. I'll edit for clarity. The overall point though is just to be able to reference the class & property within a function, but only change one of the arguments

Comment: It's not clear why the purpose of the `b` argument to `wrapper_fct` is.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of what you would write.

Comment: @chepner, ```b``` in ```wrapper_fct``` is the argument I wish to change in ```my_class```. I would still have to specify the remaining ```a,c,d,e,f``` elsewhere ... but not sure the best way to do that

Comment: Change to *what*? You need a value *and* some indication of where to use that value.

Comment: Change to whatever I provide in ```wrapper_fct```. E.g., ```wrapper_fct(my_class, b1)``` would return ```my_class(a,b1,c).my_property(d,e,f)```, ```wrapper_fct(my_class, b2)``` would return ```my_class(a,b2,c).my_property(d,e,f)```. Hope I'm not using any wrong terms when I'm referring to wrappers, classes

Comment: Note that properties in Python don't have argument like that (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property)).

Comment: @martineau - Ah, yes. I meant methods. Thanks for the update!

Comment: So you are *alway* changing the second argument to `my_class`?

Comment: @chepner That's right, whenever I call ```wrapper_fct```. And all the other variables (a,c,d,e,f) would be the same... which is why I didn't want to write those over & over

Comment: Take a look at `functools.partial`. You aren't *changing* anything in an existing instance; you are simply fixing most arguments when creating an instance.

Comment: @chepner - that's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks. Can you please answer the question with this info?

Comment: @chepner In case I want to edit class & method variables in ```my_class(a,b,c).my_method(d,e,f)```, would I only be able to use ```functools.partial``` for the class variables (```a,b,c```) and then seperately for the method variables (```d,e,f```)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After @chepner pointed me in the right direction, I think the best solution is to use the `lambda` function:

```
wrapper_fct = lambda b: my_class1(a,b,c).my_method(d,e,f)
```

In this case, I can vary `b` as much as I want while holding the class arguments `a,c`, and method arguments `d,e,f` constant. Note that with `lambda` functions, I can also vary the method arguments and/or the class arguments. For example:

```
wrapper_fct_multiple = lambda b, e: my_class1(a,b,c).my_method(d,e,f)
```

It is also possible to do this with `functools.partial`, but it's not obvious to me how I would specify both class & method arguments with functools.

Anyway, here is the solution implementation using `lambda`:

```
# define the "wrapper function" outside the loop
wrapper_fct = lambda b: my_class1(a,b,c).my_method(d,e,f)

# define the function I want to use to loop through B:
def loop_through_B(class_wrapper, b_values)
    mylist = []
    for b in b_values:
        mylist.append( class_wrapper(b) )
    return mylist  

# run:
loop_through_B(wrapper_fct, b_values=[1,2,3,4,5])

# Can make additional wrapper_fct2, wrapper_fct3, for my_class2, my_class3 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the method a dictionary of arguments, and change what the method sees by selectively updating it when calling the method.

Here's what I mean:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a, self.b, self.c = a, b, c

    def my_method(self, kwargs):
        return sum((kwargs[key] for key in kwargs.keys()))

    def __repr__(self):
      classname = type(self).__name__
      args = ', '.join((f'{v!r}' for v in (self.a, self.b, self.c)))
      return f'{classname}({args})'


instance = MyClass('a','b','c')
print(instance)  # -> MyClass('a', 'b', 'c')

kwargs = dict(d=1, e=2, f=3)
print(instance.my_method(kwargs))              # -> 6
print(instance.my_method(dict(kwargs, e=38)))  # -> 42
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't want to edit the classes themselves, so I think using functools.partial like @chepner suggested would be better for me, but your solution it a good workaround.